# Electron webContents can't register listener

Tags: javascript, electron

I can't make `WebContents` listener work. This code executes well I get Id from `await splitWindow.createView('leftView')`, but listener is not working I get no errors just that `console.log` never executes.

```
ipcMain.on("SplitMount", async () => {
  const leftId = await splitWindow.createView('leftView')
  webContents.fromId(leftId).on('will-navigate', (event, url) => {
    console.log(url)
  })

  splitWindow.windowResize()
});
```

edit: just to remove any confusion even if I check for other event it still doesn't work

```
ipcMain.on("SplitMount", async () => {
  const leftId = await splitWindow.createView('leftView')
  webContents.fromId(leftId).on('did-finish-load', () => {
    console.log('test')
     
  })

  splitWindow.windowResize()
});
```

Comment: I think we'd need more code to diagnose the issue. Is the createView function also calling `loadURL`, or `loadFile` to actually load a page? If so, could it be awaiting it, so then the did-finish-load doesn't fire since it already did?

Comment: The problem was the wrong listener. I was clicking on a page that didn't go to a new url it was just replacing the url via js. Didn't realize that was the case.